# Multiple hangfire dashboards and processing on the same server at the same time

Tags: hangfire

We have a situation where our staging and production instance are on the same server (using single IIS).  Hence we have a hang-fire server installed on this pc one for staging and to manage production.

However we can't have both our staging and our production version of hang-fire running at the same time as there are conflicts so we need to have one stopped at all times.

Both these processing would work with different databases and process different items configured by config files.

Is there anyway to have basically 2 hangfire dashboards and related processing on the same server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So my question was slightly off.  It's not hangfire we needed to run on a different port but the process that is being used to host it.

In this case we are running the hangfire as a windows service.

```
host.RunAsService();
```

However, by default it used the port 5000.  So when we had 2 windows services running they were conflicting on this port.

What we needed to do was configure our host server to run these instances on different ports.  We were able to do this by adding a port configuration to our appsettings and setting it accordingly.  We can then read that in during startup to configure what Url is used.

```
    public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
    {
        var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true); //this is not needed, but could be useful

        var settings = new ProcessingSettings();
        config.Build().GetSection("ProcessingSettings").Bind(settings);

        return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .UseUrls($"http://*:{settings.Port}");
    }
```